# Construct and label a uniform graph in NetworkX using dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, network-programming, networkx

**How can you use node position and edge information to label a graph in NetworkX?**

I like the structured nature of the hypercube_graph() instead of the randomness of the spring_layout().  I'm aware that NetworkX only plots in 2D, but the hypercube_graph() projects an N dimensional object in 2D and I would like to use this layout with my own labels. 
[image]

*For a 3 dimensional figure, the nx.Graph() is uniform (not random) but not for a 4 dimensional figure.  I am using 3D as a simple version of higher dimensional cubes.*

Currently, I have a **dictionary of nodes to edges**:

```
D_node_edge = {'pr': ['pqr'], 
               'pq': ['pqr'], 
               'p': ['pq', 'pr'], 
               'qr': ['pqr'], 
               'q': ['pq', 'qr'], 
               '0': ['p', 'q', 'r'], 
               'pqr': [], 
               'r': ['pr', 'qr']}
```

and a **dictionary of nodes to positions** within a graph:

```
D_node_pos = {'pr': (1, 0, 1), 
              'qr': (0, 1, 1), 
              'p': (1, 0, 0), 
              'pq': (1, 1, 0), 
              'q': (0, 1, 0), 
              '0': (0, 0, 0), 
              'pqr': (1, 1, 1), 
              'r': (0, 0, 1)}
```

I want to use a **DiGraph()**:

```
axis_labels = ['p','q','r']
dimension = len(axis_labels) #3 in this case

H = nx.DiGraph()
```

with the **layout of a hypercube_graph**

```
HC = nx.hypercube_graph(dimension) #dimension = 3

>>>nx.spring_layout(HC, dim = dimension)

{(1, 1, 0): array([ 0.69543835,  0.37689489,  0.48037435]), 
 (0, 1, 1): array([ 0.27055875,  0.        ,  0.36329725]), 
 (1, 0, 0): array([ 0.41149329,  0.76917215,  0.60675544]), 
 (0, 0, 1): array([ 0.        ,  0.43156976,  0.51814906]), 
 (1, 0, 1): array([ 0.33865646,  0.53760327,  0.16742205]), 
 (0, 0, 0): array([ 0.04858308,  0.73062358,  1.        ]), 
 (0, 1, 0): array([ 0.34010671,  0.27698965,  0.81225166]), 
 (1, 1, 1): array([ 0.65369567,  0.13626658,  0.        ])}
```

**Is there any way to assign the layout positions of the hypercube_graph() to my nodes using the dictionaries I've created?**

It doesn't work when I try to draw it:

```
nx.draw(H, pos = D_node_pos, with_labels = True, node_shape = 'o', arrows = True)
```

I understand that the "pos" dictionary needs to be keys= node and values= positions (e.g. 'p': array([ 0.41149329,  0.76917215,  0.60675544])) but it still didn't work :(

```
...
      File "/Users/Mu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 148, in __init__
        assert vertices.shape[1] == 2
    AssertionError
```

Comment: nx.draw can only draw 2-dimensional coordinates.  You'll need to project to 2d or else find a 3d drawing package if you need that.

Comment: That is a pretty ugly error message though and could be fixed to be more informative.

Comment: @Aric projecting to 2D is perfectly fine.  It seems as if the hypercube_graph() coordinates are projected onto 2D for both dimension 3 and 4.  Do you know how I can assign the node names to those coordinates created by the hypercube_graph()?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The pos= dictionary needs to be e.g. pos[node]=(x,y)

Comment: @Aric , I think I can figure out if i get the 2D coordinates of a N dimensional figure projected in 2D

Comment: Good - use those coordinates as values for the `pos` dictionary.

Comment: @aric do you know how to get the 2D coordinates of  N dimensional 2D projection?

Comment: That is maybe better asked as a separate question.